# Why do we test webservices on different end points?

Tags: web-services

This is the question asked in interview.Please reply to this question.

I have no idea about web services.Please reply to this question why do we test webservices on different end points.Please make sure I need an answer in your own words.

Comment: Do **get** an idea about web-services. Use Google search.

Comment: your question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Tsk tsk, if you don't know the answer to an interview question it's better off being honest and just saying that you don't know, because if I was interviewing you I'm sure I'd pick up if you don't know what you're talking about...

However for the sake of your own education: let's say we have an endpoint

test.com/api/create

although this is one endpoint, you can say there are several which can be reached with different protocols. (Think http verbs - GET, POST, PUT, PATCH...)

You probably don't want someone hitting the create endpoint with a GET protocol but only POST.

Theoretically you can test for this, but if you're going out of your way to test for these kind of things, I'd start to think you were just wasting company time rather than really testing meaningful functionality lol.

-- In many languages you define the protocol you want an endpoint to expose

Oh and be sure to mark whatever answer you use in the interview as answered ;-)